# JQuery : Radiobutton is not getting selected correctly for same control id

Tags: jquery, dynamic, radio-button

I am creating Radiobutton dynamically, and using Jquery to select the appropriate radio button based on the values from Database. Below is the sample code which is generated after render.

```
<input checked="checked" id="Claim_0" name="Temp.MyClaim" type="radio" value="True" />
                <label for="Yes">Yes</label>
                <input id="Claim_0" name="Temp.MyClaim" type="radio" value="False" />
                <label for="No">No</label>

<input id="Claim_1" name="Temp.MyClaim" type="radio" value="True" />
                <label for="Yes">Yes</label>
                <input checked="checked" id="Claim_1" name="Temp.MyClaim" type="radio" value="False" />
                <label for="No">No</label>
```

I'm using JQuery to select the values, below is sample code

```
var j = 0;
$('input:radio[id^="Claim_"]').each(function () {

    var selection = $(this)[0].defaultChecked;
    if (selection) {                        
        if ($(this).val() == "True") {
    $("input:radio[id=Claim_" + j + "]:nth(0)").attr('checked', true)
            $('#ClaimData_' + j).show();
        }
        else {
    $("input:radio[id=Claim_" + j + "]:nth(1)").attr('checked', true)
            $('#ClaimData_' + j).hide();
        }
        j++;
    }
});
```

Problem is, in final output of page, only the last radio button shown as checked, I have changed the id of each group dynamically, but still only one radio is getting selected.

Please suggest what wrong i am doing or how can i get this done.

Comment: You use linq to sql (and textboxfor) ?

Comment: So if the value is True, it should be checked, and if the value is not True it should be....wait for it....checked? Looks like there's a much easier way to do this without each().

Comment: Why are you causing the checked box to be `checked` even if the condition `selection == 'True'` is false ??

Comment: even if the condition selection == 'True' is false, i need to make the other set of radiobutton to false which I am differentiating based on "title" attribute.

Answer (score 1):

You're using the same name `Temp.MyClaim` for all radiobuttons. This is a radiobutton-group, and only one can be selected.

Answer (score 0):

Edit like this

```
$('input:radio').each(function () {

var selection = $(this).val();
if (selection == 'True') {
    $(this).attr("checked", "checked");
}
else {
    $(this).attr("checked", "checked");        
}
});
```

Comment: What's up with with the i++;? Does'nt each() already have an index?

Comment: I chagned the "Title" attribute to "title" but no luck.And I dont want to loop through all the radio button's but just only those where the "title" attribute is provided, else it will go in both the cases of if and else for all the radio button groups.

Comment: Then use $('input:radio[title^="Claim_"]')

Answer (score 0):

```
$('input[type="radio"][title^="Claim_"]').prop('checked', true);
```

You are using the same name and the same ID for all radio's, so that will mess things up for you!

Comment: isn't it possible to differentiate using "title" attribute in radiobutton?? I am new to this attribute.

Comment: You should preferrably use unique ID's or a class to select the radio's, and not the title. If you use the same name for your radio's it becomes a group of radio buttons where only one can be checked at any given time.

Comment: That really has nothing to do with this. radio groups are just plain old HTML.

Comment: View is not creating "id" "name" dynamically 'code'   @Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.ClaimEntity.Claim, "True", Model.m.ClaimEntity.Claim.Equals(true) ? new { name = "Claim_" + ViewData["count"].ToString(), id = "Claim", title = "Claim_" + ViewData["count"].ToString() } : null)                 @Html.Label("Yes")                 @Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.ClaimEntity.Claim, "False", Model.m.ClaimEntity.Claim.Equals(false) ? new { name = "Claim_" + ViewData["count"].ToString(), id = "Claim", title = "Claim_" + ViewData["count"].ToString() } : null)                 @Html.Label("No")